# closing modal when clicking on x doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have button x and i can't close modal with it. Only way i can close modal is by clicking somewhere outside of modal or refreshing page.

Here is my html:

```
<button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="modal-register">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try removing the `data-target`. Bootstrap only shows this in their documentation, without the `data-target`:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```